# How to find a particular index of a value that appears multiple times in a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel function which finds the index into `AmountNamedRange` of the second largest amount given that its corresponding `DateNamedRange` is within the past thirty days.

```
=ArrayFormula(Match(Large(If(DateNamedRange > Today() - 30, AmountNamedRange, 0), 2), AmountNamedRange, 0))
```

This works well enough as long as there are no other rows in the table with the same amount. If there is such a thing, though, this formula gives the index of the *first* row with the same amount as the second largest amount in the past thirty days. I realize that my explanation is confusing, so here's an example (assume today is 1/31/2017):

```
1    Date          Amount
2    12/2/2016     27
3    12/6/2016     66
4    12/15/2016    99
5    1/8/2017      45
6    1/20/2017     27
7    1/22/2017     18
```

In this case, the second largest amount in the past 30 days is 27 (index 6) but my formula will return index 2 because `Match` finds the first row in the table that matches the amount. How can I modify my formula to correctly return 6?

Comment: @pat2015 My criteria is that it's the index that corresponds to the value that `Large()` returns. In this case, it has to be 6 because index 2 is not within the 30 day range.

Comment: First find the first date that does match your requirement. Amend (rebuild based on the result) the parameters to MATCH() accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the same expression as second parameter of `MATCH` which you've used for `LARGE`, so it'll not just look in Amounts, but only the amounts in the last 30 days:

`=MATCH(LARGE(IF(DateNamedRange > TODAY() - 30, AmountNamedRange, 0), 2), IF(DateNamedRange > TODAY() - 30, AmountNamedRange, 0), 0)`
(it's still an array formula)

[image]